# Как нарисовать на CSS плавный изгиб?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Народ можно на CSS нарисовать элемент который выделений красной рамкой?

Comment: белый прямоугольник что-ли?)))

Comment: :)) нет, я белым прямоугольником обозначил типа "горб" который надо нарисовать

Comment: а, понял, как, хз, но в следующий раз давай адекватные картинки, у меня например для чтения SС контраст на мониторе выведен почти в ноль и блок одного цвета с фоном.... и и изгиба соответственно никакого не видно. Думаю, изгиб такой как минимум кучей кода придется делать на псевдоэлементах, я бы картинкой сделал с небольшим упрощением и дизайнеру руки поотрывал! и владельцы планшетов и смартфонов меня поддержат, ибо все эти финтифлюшки катастрофично тормозят открытие страниц на моб. устройствах... вплоть до закрытия вкладки и переход на сайт конкурента!

Comment: @СергейВ., ну, дизайнерам руки отрывать не нужно, в чём проблема использовать всего лишь один тег path в svg?) Да и на CSS не так проблемно это сделать

Comment: напишите как на CSS это сделать

Comment: @Сергійmk, хорошо, через 10-20 минут пришлю ответ=)

Comment: @Arthur А как именно это можно сделать на чистом CSS? Можно разве что добавить `clip-path` с `url`, где указано значение идентификатора `path` с SVG, но тогда смысл использовать CSS теряется. Как на CSS можно делать кривые линии? Способ накидать кучу элементов с `border-radius` не уверен, что лучшая затея.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, скорее единственная, если говорить про `border-radius`,  как вариант

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не самый хороший вариант на `CSS`:
**P.S.** *Рекомендую использовать `SVG`*

```css
:root {
  --size: 16.875rem;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
}

.block::before,
.block::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1rem;
  width: 5.2rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}

.block::before {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}

.block::after {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
}

.ellipse {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3rem;
  left: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="ellipse"></div>
</div>
```